# Searching jQuery variable full of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, variables

This may be a strange question -- Right now I have a variable that is full of HTML, and I want to use jQuery (or JS) to search that varaible for inputs with checkboxes, and return the information.

So:

```
alert($(this).parent().parent().html())
var thisIsThat = $(this).parent().parent().html();
alert(thisIsThat)
var Awesome = $(thisIsThat).find('input:checked');
```

And then after I get that variable, after a successful ajax call, I want to change a specific attribute inside of it, like so:

```
$(Awesome).attr('value', 'false');
```

Right now, "Awesome" is returning nothing, which then doesn't allow me to change the attribute like I want to. I may be on the wrong direction as well -- any advice appreciated!

Comment: `thisIsThat` is not part of `DOM`

Comment: First find out where you are starting.. so console.log($(this)).. then start from there

Comment: @Shusl How do I target thisIsThat then in jQuery? During the alert it's outputing the correct html?

Comment: If you do $(thisIsThat).find('input') does it return the number of items you expect? If not maybe your check boxes are not actually checked. Seeing the html in "thisIsThat" would definitely help.

Comment: @Nick Why not work with the actual DOM element - `$(this).parent().parent()` - rather than its HTML?

Comment: Probably you want to give a working example using http://jsfiddle.net/ or something like that...

Comment: @Nick. Your code should work. I tested it in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Tw6Q/1/. are you modifying Awesome any other place.

Comment: @CraigMacGregor -- sorry, didn't think to include the HTML! Here it is -- <td class=" sorting_1" title="11" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; ">11</td><td title="aaaa@aaaa.com" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; ">aaaa@aaaa.com</td><td title="aaaa@aaaa.com" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; ">aaaa@aaaa.com</td><td title="" style="max-width: 220px; overflow: hidden; "><input type="checkbox" class="tenantenabled" value="false"></td>

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It seems that taking the .html() out and manipulating it as a DOM element (like jhonraymos and Anthony Grist suggested) worked. Thank you all every much (again). You're awesome! (and thank you Shusl for your early response and making of JS fiddle!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
var thisIsThat = $(this).parent().parent();
alert(thisIsThat)
var Awesome = $(thisIsThat).find('input:checked');
```

In this case `thisIsThat` is a object and you can find anything using that object

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked perfectly. I just removed the ':checked' selector as I wanted to hit both checked and unchecked inputs (and there's only one input in this row).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example showing the same basic idea running off of a string which finds the checkbox fine and unchecks it.

```
<div id="out"></div>​
<script>
    var htmlStr = '<div><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/></div>';
    var temp = $(htmlStr);
    var cb = temp.find("input:checked");
    cb.attr("checked",false);
    jQuery("#out").append(cb);
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uA6LK/)

The problem I am betting is that you are checking the checkbox manually. It will not update the DOM attribute when you do that.

Here is a basic example to show you the problem.

```
<div id="one">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<button>Tell</button>​

<script>
    function tellMe(){
        var myDiv = jQuery("#one");
        var html1 = myDiv.html();
        console.log(html1);
    }

    jQuery("button").click(tellMe);  
</script>
```

Take a look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uA6LK/1/) of the code above.

Open up the console, and click on the button. You will see it unchecked. Check the checbox and click the button again, same html is outputted even though the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this! I was running the code inside of a loop, so it was updating regularly I believe, so the other solution worked. Thank you again!

Answer (score -3):

change

```
var Awesome = $(thisIsThat).find('input:checked');
```

to

```
var Awesome = $(thisIsThat).find('input[type=checked]');

now loop over it

Awesome.each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
     $(this).attr('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with regular expressions, beside in validation I guess. How do I use regular expressions in this situation?

Comment: -1 For recommending using Regex to parse HTML.